# the set of all solutions of the system $ax+by+cz =0, dx+ey+cz=0$ forms a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

To show that the set of all solutions of the system $ax+by+cz =0, dx+ey+cz=0$ forms a subspace.

Subtracting  we get $x = \frac{e-b}{a-d}y$ and putting this in any one of the equations we get $z= \frac{bd-ae}{c(a-d)}y$.

Thus the solution set is span$\{(e-b,a-d,\frac{bd-ae}{c} )^T\}$ and hence a subspace.

Is the solution correct?

Comment: The subset will be a subspace if and only if the addition of two of them and the multiplication by a scalar belong to the set. But this is obviously true. With your method you have to study what happens when $c=0$ or $a=d$, which is much more tedious.

Comment: What if $c=0?$ Or $a=d?$ Are not they two subspaces? Is not the intersection of two subspaces a subspace?

Comment: What is $d$? It isn't a coefficient anywhere in your system.